# Why we use not symbol in <!doctype> declaration in html? And what happened when we are not declared it?

Tags: html

I m fresher in web technologies.my question is what is use of not(!) In doctype declaration.

Comment: It's not 'not', don't mix with javascript, it's just a tag

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because the duplicate link doesn't really address the actual question or provide a truly correct answer. The answer is that HTML is based on an older markup language called Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML) and, in that language, tags that begin with `<!` have a special meaning to the parser. Keep in mind that in HTML, comments start with `<!` as well. The `!` means "logical NOT" in JavaScript, but not in SGML or HTML. **[Here's more on SGML.](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/intro/sgmltut.html#h-2.3.3)**